# Garbage collection on Map and WeakMap collections in es6

Tags: javascript, dictionary, garbage-collection, ecmascript-6, weakmap

I was reading the WeakMap's description and it said:

> In native WeakMaps, references to key objects are held "weakly", which means that **they do not prevent garbage collection in case there would be no other reference to the object**.

From reading this, my understanding is that WeakMaps are used in instances where you're trying to take advantage of JavaScript's garbage collection. What I don't understand fundamentally is the line I bolded.

Why, in a normal Map, would objects with no references to them not be garbage collected? What's the advantage to this, and do I have to explicitly delete from normal Maps?

Comment: That means that unless the keys have other, independent references, the  gc can reclaim their memories.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I comprehend the concept at face value, but I feel like without an example I can't really understand how the gc really works.

Comment: Right, that's a little too abstract. I tried to come up with a little example below. Perhaps that will be a little more useful.

Comment: *"Why, in a normal Map, would objects with no references to them not be garbage collected?"* because the map itself has a reference to the object. As long as there is a reference, the object is not gced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why, in a normal Map, would objects with no references to them not be garbage collected?" because the map itself has a reference to the object. As long as there is a reference, the object is not gced. - Felix Kling

Comment: Will the object be gced if it is deleted from the map, i.e. map.delete(key)?

Answer (score 1):

in a normal `Map`, the `Map` *is* a reference to the object